# Redirection in an ajax login form after a login success

Tags: javascript, ajax, ajaxform

I am working on a website, trying to fix the code from a previous developer, and I am hardly struggling with a modal ajax login form.

When I click on "login" button, a modal opens, mentionning user input, password input, and connect button.
when I enter correct information and click on the button, nothing happens on client-side and the modal stays open on the screen.
BUT when I retry to login, i got a label in the modal indicating that I am already logged-in.

In fact, login was made. The window just does not refresh, and connection success do not lead back to the current page ("home" for instance, or whatever page I am on currently).

Has someone an idea?
Thanks in advance

(I put various JS code below)

```js
// Run our login form ajax
 $('#modal-login #form-login').on('submit', function(e) {

  // Stop the form from submitting so we can use ajax.
  e.preventDefault();

  // Check what form is currently being submitted so we can return the right values for the ajax request.
  var form_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');

  // Remove any messages that currently exist.
  $('.modal-login-content > p.message').remove();

  // Check if we are trying to login. If so, process all the needed form fields and return a faild or success message.
  if ( form_id === 'login' ) {
   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: modal_login_script.ajax,
    data: {
     'action'     : 'ajaxlogin', // Calls our wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin
     'username'   : $('#form-login #login_user').val(),
     'password'   : $('#form-login #login_pass').val(),
     'rememberme' : ($('#form-login #rememberme').is(':checked'))?"TRUE":"FALSE",
     'login'      : $('#form-login input[name="login"]').val(),
     'security'   : $('#form-login #security-login').val()
    },
    beforeSend : function(){
     $('.ml-modal' ).addClass( 'is-active' );
    },
    success: function(results) {

     // Check the returned data message. If we logged in successfully, then let our users know and remove the modal window.
     if(results.loggedin === true) {
      $('.modal-login-content > h2').after('<p class="message success"></p>');
      $('.modal-login-content > p.message').text(results.message).show();

      $('#overlay, .login-popup').delay(5000).fadeOut('300m', function() {
       $('#overlay').remove();
      });
                        window.location.href = updateQueryStringParameter( modal_login_script.registration_redirect, 'nocache', ( new Date() ).getTime() );
     } else {
      $('.modal-login-content > h2').after('<p class="message error"></p>');
      $('.modal-login-content > p.message').text(results.message).show();
     }
    },
    complete : function(){
     $('.ml-modal' ).removeClass( 'is-active' );
    }
   });
  } else {
   // if all else fails and we've hit here... something strange happen and notify the user.
   $('.modal-login-content > h2').after('<p class="message error"></p>');
   $('.modal-login-content > p.message').text('Please refresh your window and try again.');
  }
 });
```

Comment: `window.location.href="/success"` is your friend

Comment: what do you mean? do I have to replace the entire code " window.location.href = updateQueryStringParameter( modal_login_script.registration_redirect, 'nocache', ( new Date() ).getTime() );  " ?

Comment: ok, problem solved thanks to a different way.

But for my own progression, can someone explain differences between the code I found, and the one written by Marc?
Thanks.